# Socket.IO duplicated message

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I'm trying to build a chat application using Laravel, with node js server, socketio and redis. What I have is this:

**Client JS:**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3005');
 var room = '17';
  $("#send").click(function(){
    content = $("textarea").val();
    id =$("#id").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{route('send.message')}}",
      method: "POST",
      data: {content, id, room},
      success: function(){
      }
    });
  });

  socket.on('cacad', function(message){
          console.log(message); //multiple copies here
      });

  socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("Connected!");
    socket.emit('room', room);
  });
```

**Laravel Controller:**

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){
 event(new EventName($request->all()));
  $message = new Message;
  $message->message = $request->content;
  $redis = LRedis::connection();
  $redis->publish('chat-channel', json_encode($request->all()));
  $message->save();
}
```

**Node Server:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var redis = require('ioredis');

var myMessage;
var redis_client = redis.createClient();

redis_client.subscribe('chat-channel');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    redis_client.on('message', function(channel, message) {
      var myData = JSON.parse(message);
        socket.broadcast.to('17').emit('cacad', 'u i u a a');
    });


    socket.on('room', function(room){
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log("disconnected!");
    });
});


http.listen(3005, function() {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3005');
});
```

I am trying to broadcast a message `u i u a a` in room 17. But when I receive it in the console, it shows multiple copies of it, 2x-4x. In the Laravel controller I publish a message using redis and I subscribe to it in node server. It is received successfully, but the problem lies with the multiple copies of the message (client side).

Please where is it wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: Why you using PHP and NodeJS, performing an AJAX request to send the client's message ? as a chat application it is not efficient to send it that way. Because each request contains the HEADERS, creating a new request which is a connection and then close it. You already have the sockets. simply use the emit ? refer to https://socket.io/docs/client-api/ they have a great example of a chat ..

Comment: I perform an AJAX so the data is saved in the database. How else would you touch Laravel's controller other than through AJAX in this situation? I'm looking forward to you response.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel but as I can see, both of your Laravel and NodeJS are using the same redis correct ? why not simply saving what you need just in the nodejs ? there is a different advantage of using the Laravel code ?

Comment: My main application is using Laravel. But back to my questions, it doesn't really answer why I get duplicated messages. Any reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty convinced I found the issue although I had to search a bit about those simple API usage because I'm not using the library lately.

Looking at the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) it's explain your issue pretty clearly.

Here you are listening to a new connection,

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
```

If the client asked to join to a specific room, you join him:

```
socket.on('room', function(room){
    socket.join(room);
```

So far it's like the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#joining-and-leaving):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

But your issue is with your emit, on each client connection, you listen to a message from your redis. Then you broadcast it to the room with an emit of the connected client.

Instead of that, you can do this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('room', function(room){
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log("disconnected!");
    });
});

redis_client.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    var myData = JSON.parse(message);
      io.to('17').emit('cacad', 'u i u a a');
  });
```

Comment: So does it show duplicated message because of the number of clients connected? I only have one client connected.

Comment: Thank you! It's working. I am just a bit confused using Redis and Socket IO together. Still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens on the socket-io-client side. not on the server-side. when I was using react-js for the client-side. I received the same message multiple times.

with the same server, I imported socket-io-client 4.4.1 in the vanilla js front-end project. then I didn't get multiple messages... :)

try use latest socket io client versions. i think they have fixed the issue in the latest versions..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).